# How to re-order List inside Grails entity where order managed by indexColumn

Tags: java, groovy, entity, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I have an entity like this

```
class Parent {
        
   //...
   List<Child> children
        
   static mapping = {
      //..
      children joinTable: [name:'ParentChild', key:'ParentID', column:'ChildID'],
         cascade: 'all', lazy: false, indexColumn: [name: 'OrderIndex', type: Byte]
                
      }
}
```

How can I re-order and save changes to my database?

I have tried the code below:

```
@Transactional
Parent reOrderChildren(long parentId, CustomChildrenComparator comparator) {
   Parent parent = Parent.findById(parentId)
   parent.children.sort(comparator)
   parent.save()
}
```

but the result is `SqlException`

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation
> of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ParentChild'. Cannot insert duplicate
> key in object 'ParentChild'. The duplicate key value is (15, 1761).

But database does not contain any duplicates. As far as I understand **hibernate** try to insert new records in `ParentChild` table instead of update `indexColumn`s of existing ones

Comment: It is surprising to me that `parent.save()` and `parent.save(validate: true)` are behaving differently.

Comment: The code at https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/478174559496be0bae66bb2b35e269ee6538f185/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormInstanceApi.groovy#L318 is supposed to default `validate` to `true` if it isn't specified.  If you can file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues with a sample app, we can investigate.  Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks for your notes. It is my fault. In first case method was as is (`parent.save()`) but in second case it was transactional method (`parentService.save(parent)`) executes `parent.save(true)`

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Are lists managed by  **indexColumn-feature** support items re-ordering?

Comment: AFAIK, reordering a list in GORM is sometimes tricky. I usually danced the problem around by assigning `null` to the list prop, and then assign a new list instance to it